# HQL query generates AntlrRuntime.NoViableAltException since NHibernate upgrade

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I'm upgrading NHibernate from v 2.0 to 3.2.  All our unit tests work Ok except for one which tries to execute the HQL query :

```
select  from SkillRequirementCoverage src  inner join src.Skill as skill  inner join src.User as user  inner join src.Job as job  left outer join skill.SkillDomain as skillDomain  where src.ApplicationId = ?  and user.Category = ?
```

which fails with the Antlr exception - it was working before.

The query is executed using `HibernateTemplate.Find<T>(hqlRequest, parameters);`

Anyone any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HQL parser in NH2.0 is less strict than in more recent versions.  At least in NH3.2 a query should not start with a select if no column is specified.  The following forms are valid:

```
from Entity e

select e from Entity e

select e.PropA from Entity e
```